# 'Object(...) is not a function' in Amplify Authenticator in vue2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, aws-amplify

I would like to use the AWS Amplify Authenticator in a js vue2 app. The manual that I used can be found here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/tree/legacy/legacy/amplify-ui-vue#recommended-usage
But I end up getting an `Object(...) is not a function` error.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.eval (index.js?2bbc:22:1)
    at eval (index.js:12544:30)
    at Module../node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-vue/dist/index.js (sign-in.js:167:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:859:30)
    at fn (app.js:151:20)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/pages/auth/SignInPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2:77)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/pages/auth/SignInPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (sign-in.js:179:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:859:30)
    at fn (app.js:151:20)
    at eval (SignInPage.vue?0642:1:1)
```

The page `SignInPage.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <amplify-authenticator />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import '@aws-amplify/ui-vue'
import { onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components'

export default {
    name: 'SignInPage',
    created() {
        this.unsubscribeAuth = onAuthUIStateChange((authState, authData) => {
            this.authState = authState
            this.user = authData
        })
    },
    data() {
        return {
            user: undefined,
            authState: undefined,
            unsubscribeAuth: undefined,
        }
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.unsubscribeAuth()
    },
}
</script>
```

I tried both the example on the top of the page, as the bottom examples (migrated section), both ending up with the same error. Can anybody help me out?

**Update 1:**

SignInPage.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <authenticator />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-vue'
import '@aws-amplify/ui-vue/styles.css'

export default {
    name: 'SignInPage',
    components: { Authenticator },
}
</script>
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.9",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-vue": "^2.3.11",
    "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.20",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
}
```

Comment: Where does this error occure?

Comment: @Ifaruki, I get the error when the page above is loading. The page is called 'SignInPage.vue', I will update the description

Comment: Apart from missing trailing semi colons ... I do not see anything different in your code ...

Comment: Specifically, which line in the above page gives the error? (You can use the debugger to find out)

Comment: Which versions are you running? I cannot recreate this using your code snippet...

Comment: This error usually occurs when you have miss-matching Amplify packages. And although you've not shared your package.json, I can see you're following the older version of the guide. There are more up-to-date examples found in the main branch, [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/tree/main/examples/vue/src/pages/ui/components/authenticator).

Comment: @Lissy93 Added a part of the package.json . This file is also missing in the examples, so I am guessing for package names/versions.

I tried the example code, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Lissy93 please note that this is a vue2 page, I cannot update to vue3 for this app because of other dependecies. 
(I did get it working in vue3)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries the following seems to solve it, with the help of this page: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components

Steps I have taken:

- uninstall the all the aws-amplify packages
- (re-)add aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-components packages
- remove the @aws-amplify related imports from the SignIn page
- add the following to the main.js

```
    import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components/loader';
        
    applyPolyfills().then(() => {
      defineCustomElements(window);
    });
        
    Vue.config.ignoredElements = [/amplify-\w*/];
```

SignInPage.vue

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <amplify-authenticator />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'SignInPage',
    }
    </script>
```